# Function not executed and UI freezes

Tags: c#, .net-core

there is such a code for Yandex Music, through the library https://github.com/K1llMan/Yandex.Music.Api
I'm trying to make a UI binding so that the application is not console, I created a project on **NetCore 3.1 + WPF** made a window, fields for entering a login and password, after pressing the login button **loginb** the entire UI freezes and **Console.WriteLine** in the VS output does not show anything. Please tell me how can I solve this?

```
namespace YDClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        }

        private void LaunchGitHubSite(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Launch the GitHub site...
        }

        private void loginb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DebugSettings debugSettings = new DebugSettings(@"C:\yandex_music", @"C:\yandex_music\log.txt");
            AuthStorage authStorage = new AuthStorage(debugSettings);
            var api = new YandexMusicApi();
            api.User.Authorize(authStorage, name.Text, pass.Text);
            if (authStorage.IsAuthorized)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Auth true");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Auth false");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Please tell me how can I solve this?"_ - Learn how to use the debugger. My first guess would be `api.User.Authorize` is a blocking call and for some reason does not return.

Comment: The call to `api.User.Authorize` will block your applications UI thread and results in a deadlock. `Authorize` is doing this `AuthorizeAsync(storage, login, password).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`.

Comment: It's just that no matter what I do, I can't get the output to the VS console of information. Even before loading this method. for example
            `InitializeComponent();
             Console.WriteLine("Starting");`

will not output this line.

Comment: I can not understand, the console works with the GUI no.

Comment: In a GUI Project, I'd use a logging framework instead of Console.WriteLine.

Comment: @Fildor I switched to Debug.WriteLine, I see the lines, now I'm trying to understand what freezes the UI

Comment: And in an EventHandler, which this seems to be, you can go async. So you can make it `private async void loginb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` and then await the async calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loginb` function is not async method. So, when your codes executing, I/O request blocks continuation of the method. You have to change method as following;

```
private async Task loginb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ....
  await api.User.Authorize(authStorage, name.Text, pass.Text);
  ....
```

After making method `loginb` async, you have to use await in I/O operations.

### What's going on in the background? Let's deep dive

*Our apps consist of two main operations.*

*1. I/O Bound Operations*

*When you making I/O operations in your code, main thread calls native Windows API in OS level for making I/O request. Then OS generates IRP for this I/O request. This IRP goes to network driver and then queued in network driver IRP Queue. Network board gets IRP from IRP Queue and makes request. If you don't use asynchronity in your code, main thread will be blocked by this request and not continue to executing codes before IRP completed. But main thread actually nothing do in here. It's only waits for completion of IRP request by network board. So you have to use `async/await` keywords to make it non-blocking. After using `async/await`, your main thread will not be blocked by IRP request and continue to executing codes. So, your UI will not freeze.*

*2. CPU Bound Operations*

*When your app contains heavy calculations or hard processes you should do this in different thread for gaining performance. With this approach, heavy calculation will be done in another thread in another core of CPU. You can achive this by using `await Task.Run(()....`* method.